Error occurred in 'make' command for modifying SAMBA 4.20.2 in ubuntu 22.04.4
I downloaded samba source 4.20.2 and built and installed it on ubuntu 22.04.4 server successfully.
I am planning to modify a few sources for use within the company, build them, and then use them. I am trying to call a function in an external library file, for example libxxx.so , from source3/smbd/server.c. At this time, I tried modifying wscript or wscript_build and building, but it failed.
Modified sources and results are as belows.

wscript file in samba_dev(source top directory) :
...

def build(bld):
    '''build all targets'''
    bld.env.LIBPATH.extend(['/usr/local/samba/lib/yyy', '/samba_dev/bin/default/source3'])
    bld.env.LIB.extend(['xxx'])

...

wscript_build file in samba_dev/source3
...

bld.SAMBA3_BINARY('smbd/smbd',
                source='smbd/server.c smbd/smbd_cleanupd.c',
                deps='''
                     xxx
                     CMDLINE_S3
                     smbd_base
                     REG_FULL
                     ''',
                install_path='${SBINDIR}')

...

root@krb5:/samba_dev# ./configure --> success

root@krb5:/samba_dev# make
PYTHONHASHSEED=1 WAF_MAKE=1  ./buildtools/bin/waf build
Waf: Entering directory `/samba_dev/bin/default'
Selected embedded Heimdal build
Checking project rules ...
ERROR: target smbd/smbd: dependency target xxx not declared


I want to hear advices or hints for solving this problem.
